# ¿Cómo podría hacer esto en php?

Tags: php, html, formularios

me gustaría saber cómo podría hacer para que cuando un usuario ponga un email ya registrado en el input de registro le salga un error debajo de forma inmediata. He hecho un poco de código de PHP pero no ha funcionado, supongo que es debido a que la función $_POST únicamente envía datos una vez presionado el botón de submit. CODES:
HTML:

```
<div class="form_email">
  <label for="email">
    ¿Cuál es su e-mail? <span class="info_email">Solo lo usaremos para enviarte actualizaciones sobre tu postulación. </span>
  </label>
  <input type="text" name="email" pattern="[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\.[^@\s]+" title="Introduzca un email correcto." maxlength="30" required />
</div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
include './assets/php/data.php';
$email = $_GET['email'];
$buscarCorreo = "SELECT * from register WHERE correo={'$email'}";
$resultado = $conn->query($buscarCorreo);
$contador = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
if (isset($_POST["email"])) {

    if ($email == 1) {
        print '<span class="error"> ¡Este email ya está en uso!</span>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Si quieres que aparezca el aviso sin necesidad de recargar la página una vez que hubo respuesta por parte  del servidor, entonces vas a necesitar manejar la petición vía AJAX.

Comment: Claro, para que fuese "de forma inmediata" tendrías que controlar que al terminar el ingreso del input del correo, se haga la petición ajax y retorne la respuesta. De otro modo tendrías que hacerlo durante el envío del formulario el cuál es con la recarga como menciona Beta.

Comment: Entiendo, pues me pongo con el tema de AJAX, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes estar pendiente dele evento `.focusout()` que es cuando el usuario deja de escribir (También podrías ver el evento `.keypress()` pero son mas solicitudes según la cantidad de teclas )

1. Crear un arachivo php llamado `verificaremail.php` ahi es donde se verificara el correo.

```html
<?php
//aqui verificas el correo   devuelve un true si existe  o un flase si no 

echo true;

?>
```

2. crear un label oculta con el id `verificar`

```html
 <label id="verificar" style="display:none">Este correo ya esta regustradi</label>
```

3. Agrega el cdn de Jquery

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

4. Envia la solicitud

```html
<script>
 $("#email").focusout(function() {
        
        //obtenemos el texto del input
        let email = $(this).val();

         var url = "verificaremail.php";
          $.ajax({
              type:"POST",
              url: url,
              data: {"email": email}, //enviamos el valor
              success: function(data){
                      $("#verificar").show();
              }
          });
          return false;

 });

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Nos ería la forma más elegante de hacerlo, pero podría realizarse con php si es lo que quieres realmente

Bajo el input del email puedes añadir una etiqueta la cual solo se mostraría si el error email existe:

```
if(isset($_GET["error"]) && $_GET["error"] == "email"){
    echo "<p>Email ya registrado<p>";
}
```

Después solo tienes añadir en tu código que en el caso de que el email esté registrado redireccione a la página.php?error=email. Y en ese caso si aparecerá dicho mensaje bajo el input del email

Cómo te digo no es lo más elegante, pero si tienes que hacerlo en php si o si es una opción